# File downloading as 0 byte. If debug it download correct file

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am trying to download file as below from a url. If debug the code the file download successfully
Without debug it give 0 byte file.What I am missing here?

I cannot use Async because of certain business logic

```
public  void download_attachments(string file_id)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = client.GetAsync(@"https://xxxxxxxxxx/api/Attachments/DownloadAttachment/" + file_id).Result;
    
    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\d\"+ Regex.Replace(response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName, @"(\[|""|\])", ""), FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I cannot use Async because of certain business logic" -- that doesn't make any sense.  You ought to be using async.  Making the required changes to support that can sometimes be painful, but not doing so leads to the risk of deadlocks.  In your case, you can try making your method `async void` (in addition to awaiting `GetAsync`) to see if that fixes the problem, though typically you should avoid its usage.

Comment: @KirkWoll if i use Async void and await GetAsync it download successfully. is there any other method i can download the file as sync instead of async

Comment: I've had success using `HttpWebRequest` in situations where I can't introduce `async` as its implementation predates async/await.

Comment: Are you certain the process running in release mode has permission to write to that location?

Comment: @EricJ. yes permission is there

Comment: First you [block on `GetAsync`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), then you don't await `CopyToAsync` so it returns before copying anything. You have [synchronous `CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-6.0#system-io-stream-copyto(system-io-stream)), and you must either await `GetAsync` or switch to `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: Please note that you have the potential for a directory traversal attack vulnerability because you use potentially untrusted input to create a filepath in the expression `new FileStream(@"C:\d\"+ Regex.Replace(response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName, @"(\[|""|\])", ""), FileMode.CreateNew)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely having this problem because the method exits before the task returned by `CopyToAsync()` completes.

Either make your method asynchronous

```
public async Task download_attachments(string file_id)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://xxxxxxxxxx/api/Attachments/DownloadAttachment/" + file_id);
    // WARNING: potential directory traversal vulnerability
    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\d\"+ Regex.Replace(response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName, @"(\[|""|\])", ""), FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }
}
```

or use the synchronous method `CopyTo()`.

```
public void download_attachments(string file_id)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = client.GetAsync(@"https://xxxxxxxxxx/api/Attachments/DownloadAttachment/" + file_id).Result;
    // WARNING: potential directory traversal vulnerability
    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\d\"+ Regex.Replace(response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName, @"(\[|""|\])", ""), FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        response.Content.CopyTo(fs, null, default);
    }
}
```

If you continue down the synchronous route, it would be best to avoid use of Async methods and find a synchronous alternative to `client.GetAsync()`.

Comment: @GSerg deadlocks are always there. async/await doesn't avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Yes, [it does](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) @HasanManzak. Were you thinking about RDBMS deadlocks which are very irrelevant?

Comment: @GSerg I'm not trying to be cocky, but I know the article, I've read it before :) What it points to is "whatever you do, do not wait in the same context". So async/await doesn't avoid deadlocks, not waiting in the same execution context does. That's my two cents.